# Setting up docker nodejs application with local npm dependencies

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

We want to start containerizing our applications, but we have stumbled upon some issues with local dependencies.

We have a single git repository, in which we have numerous node packages, under "shared" folder, and applications that require these packages.

So let's say our folder structure is as follows:

```
src/
├── apps
│   └── my_app
└── shared
    └── shared_module
```

in my_app package.json we have the following dependency:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "shared-module": "file:../../shared/shared_module"
  }
}
```

The issue here is that because we want to move "my_app" to run in a container, we need to npm install our local dependency.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it's possible but a little bit ugly. The problem for you is that Docker is very restrictive when it comes to its *build context*. I'm not sure how familiar you are already with that concept, so here is the introduction from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> The `docker build` command builds an image from a Dockerfile and a *context*.

For example, `docker build .` uses `.` as its *build context*, and since it's not specified otherwise, `./Dockerfile` as the Dockerfile. Files or paths outside the *build context* cannot be referenced in the Dockerfile (so no `COPY ..`).

The issue for you is that during a Docker build, the *build context* cannot be left. If you have multiple applications that you want to build, you would normally add a `Dockerfile` for each app.

```
src/
├── apps   
│   ├── my_app
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── my_other_app
│       └── Dockerfile
└── shared
    └── shared_module
```

Naturally, you would `cd` into `my_app` and use `docker build .` to build the application's Docker image. The issue with this is that you can't access `../../shared` from the build, since it's outside of the context.

So you need to make sure both `apps` and `shared` is in the *build context*. One way would be to place all `Dockerfile` in `src` like so:

```
src/
├── Dockerfile.my_app
├── Dockerfile.my_other
├── apps
│   ├── my_app
│   └── my_other_app
└── shared
    └── shared_module
```

You can then build the applications by explicitly specifying the context and the Dockerfile:

```
src$ docker build -f Dockerfile.my_app .
```

Alternatively, you can keep the Dockerfiles inside `my_app` and `my_other_app`, and point to them:

```
src$ docker build -f apps/my_app/Dockerfile .
```

That should also work. In both cases, the build is executed from within `src`, which means you need to pay a little attention to the paths in the Dockerfile. The *working directory* is still `src`:

```
COPY ./apps/my_app /src/apps/my_app
```

By mirroring the folder structure you have locally, you should be able to make your dependencies work without any changes:

```
RUN mkdir -p /src
COPY ./shared /src/shared
COPY ./apps/my_app /src/apps/my_app
RUN cd /src/apps/my_app && npm install
```

Hope that helps you get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will try this and comment here.

Comment: someone manage to build docker with local NPM such as:"shared-module": "file:../../shared/shared_module"? I am getting cb() never called

Comment: sumble with the same prob. Ithink the way to that is withs shared volumes.. 
but still I can't to that.